# laravel adjacency list - get subquery exists depth

Tags: laravel, recursive-query, adjacency-list

rootCategory is HasOne relation:

```
public function rootCategory()
{
    return $this->hasOne(PartnerCategory::class, 'partner_id', 'id')->where('partner_category_main', 1);
}
```

then:

```
$categories = Partner::restaurants()->with('rootCategory')->get()->pluck('rootCategory')
```

then I need to know if rootCategory has childs with depth >1 and doing in CategoryResource:

```
$this->descendants()->whereDepth('>', 1)->exists()
```

but it making much more queries. How I can to query this same time with rootCategory relation?

I tried `with(['rootCategory' => function($q) {return $q->descendants();}])` but it not working

Comment: Is `whereDepth` a query scope or is it `where('depth', ...)`? Instead of querying the existence inside the `CategoryResource`, you could load a count. (`withCount` or `withAggregate`).

Comment: withCount works like this:         $categories = Partner::restaurants()->with(['rootCategory' => function(HasOne $q) {
            $q->withCount(['descendants as is_deep_tree' => function ($q) {
               $q->whereDepth('>',1);
            }]);
        }])

Comment: how it would look withAggreaget? withCount get me 2x faster result - thanks

Comment: `withAggregate` is similar to `withCount`. The query would be the same since `withCount` just uses `withAggregate` in the background. `withAggregate(['descendants as is_deep_tree' => function ($q) { ... }], '*', 'count');`

Answer (score 0):

### Count SubQuery - WhereCount

You can get subquery row count with the "whereCount" function.

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Example with your code:

```php
$categories =
  Partner::restaurants()
    ->withCount('rootCategory', function (Builder $query) {
       $query->descendants()->whereDepth('>', 1)->exists();
    })
    ->get()
    ->pluck('rootCategory');
```

Comment: I don't need filter, I need bool field exists or not

Comment: Oh, I see. Now I understand. I will modify my answer.